# How to stub CocoaLumberjack or NSLog with OCMockito

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing, mocking, ocmockito

I can stub/verify a class method, but I'm having difficulty with defined macros. I'm trying to test that one of my methods calls DDLogInfo.

It's defined like so in the CocoaLumberjack source

```
#define DDLogInfo(frmt, ...)    LOG_MAYBE(LOG_ASYNC_ENABLED, LOG_LEVEL_DEF, DDLogFlagInfo,    0, nil, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, frmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All standard `DDLog` macros call `+[DDLog log:level:flag:context:file:function:line:tag:format:]`, so with OCMock, you would verify that `DDLogInfo` was called by:

```c
- (void)testMethodCallsDDLogInfo {
    id mockDDLog = OCMClassMock([DDLog class]);

    [obj methodThatCallsDDLogInfo];

    OCMVerify([mockDDLog log:YES level:DDLogLevelAll flag:DDLogFlagInfo context:0 file:[OCMArg anyPointer] function:[OCMArg anyPointer] line:58 tag:[OCMArg any] format:[OCMArg any]]);
}
```

Unfortunately, with this strategy you must hard-code several values, as OCMock does not have a way to specify a generic non-pointer argument.